# Can I use "the then" to refer to a previous name of something?

Tags: expressions

Is the use of "the then" in the following sentence correct? (That is, the pub that is now called "the Hops" used to be called "Addy's" back when "he" used to be a regular; it's still the same pub, with the same owners – they've just changed the name.)

> Back in the day, he used to be a regular at the Hops (the then Addy's).

If not, what could I say instead, to convey the same meaning?

(I have a hard time thinking of appropriate tags for this question, so if anyone can think of further tags, please feel free to add them :) )

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Not really, no – that only confirms what I already knew. You, on the other hand, have answered my question in your comments below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I partially agree with James K that the sentence is a little hard to understand at first reading, but I wouldn't go as far as he does.

Referring to an old name of something by saying "then [old name]" or "the then [old name]" is reasonably common. In my humble opinion it's an awkward phrase and I rarely use it, but there are enough fluent speakers out there who do that I don't think you could legitimately call it wrong or unheard of.

But yeah, I'd use more words. I'd say, "back then it was called" or "then known as" or some such.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a couple of readings to understand what you wanted to say.  I find your expression confusing.

Instead, I'd suggest "...at *The Hops* (then called *Addy's*)"

The use of a fuller expression, with a proper verb, in the brackets is clearer.  Using italics for the names of things is a typographical trick.  It's optional, but it helps set off the name of the pub from the rest of the sentence.

Another option is “. . . at *the Hops* (formerly *Addy's*)”. It’s concise, easily understood, and pretty solid grammatically.

However, if it is common knowledge that the pub has changed its name, the simple solution is

> He used to be a regular at *Addy's*.

Since common knowledge is assumed, there is no need to mention the new name of the pub.

Comment: Thank you! You're right about the use of italics – my mistake! As for your suggestion, I see that it's easier to process, but isn't there a difference between the two? To me, your suggestion implies a situation where I'm informing my addressee about what the place used to be called back when the "he" was a regular, whereas the intended situation is one where my addressee is fully aware that the pub used to be called *Addy's* and I'm just adding it to acknowledge what we both know. That is, I need a short form for "though, of course, it used to be called Addy's back then, as we both know".

Comment: You could just have " .... The Hops (Addy's)"   That is sufficient to remind your reader.  **But** if "my addressee is fully aware that the pub used to be called Addy's"  Then I would recommend not saying anything at all.   Just say "He used to be a regular at Addy's"   You both know that it now has a new name, but since you both know that, it is irrelevant.

Comment: Another option is “. . . at the Hops (formerly Addy's)”. It’s concise, easily understood, and pretty solid grammatically.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan,  thanks - I've adoped that

Comment: I don't know about elsewhere, but in the UK it is perfectly normal to use 'the then', 'my then' etc about former states or things - the then Bay Hotel (it's now called the Sea View Hotel), the then chairman (he isn't now), the then Mrs Jones (she has remarried), my then wife (I have remarried).

Comment: ... my then wife — I could also have divorced or been widowed.

Comment: Thank you all! @MichaelHarvey Yes, exactly – I've seen it used that way many times; I just wasn't sure whether it could be used about mere name changes as well, so a big thank you for answering this for me!

Comment: "my then wife"  seems fine.  "the then Addy's"  is unclear and confused me.

Comment: @JamesK - 'the then Addy's Bar, now called The Hops' might have been clearer.